# Display issue with Adobe PDF viewer (i.e. axInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll) in windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, window, adobe

I have a .net Windows form program that uses the abovementioned dll to display PDF.

I developed it in window xp and it looked alright, but when I deployed it to a Win7 machine, the length of the PDF viewer became longer then the windows form (i.e.: the bottom part is cut off the window).

has anyone encountered this before?